# How to split a file in chunk to send them over BLE with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, base64, bluetooth-lowenergy, chunks

The question is as title. I have a custom device running Linux that can receive commands via BLE. What I basically want to do is take a file, encode that in base64, split it in chunks and send every chunk to the device one after the other. The device will do the rest.
I am able to base64 encode a file but I didn't find a method to split it with Flutter into chunks.

Ang suggestion?

Many thanks